# Sequelize postgres - calculating avg of column in nested model (error: missing FROM-clause entry for table...)

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

In my Postgres db, I have a `units` table that has a one-to-many relationship to a `lessons` table, which in turn has a one-to-many relationship to an `exercises` table. I am trying to use Sequelize.js to select a set of the units and their average exercise completion.

This raw SQL query works perfectly:

```
SELECT U.Unit_id,
    Unit_number,
    Unit_title,
    Coalesce(Avg(E.Exercise_completion)) AS Avg_exercise_completion
        FROM Units U
        LEFT JOIN Lessons L
                ON U.Unit_id = L.Unit_id
        LEFT JOIN Exercises E
                ON L.Lesson_id = E.Lesson_id
    GROUP BY U.Unit_id
    ORDER BY Unit_number
    LIMIT 12;
```

I tried to translate it into Sequelize.js:

```
const units = await Unit.findAll({
  attributes: [
    ['unit_id', 'id'],
    ['unit_number', 'number'],
    ['unit_title', 'title'],
    [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('lessons.exercises.exercise_completion')), 'avgCompletion'],
  ],
  include: {
    model: Lesson,
    attributes: [],
    include: [{ model: Exercise, attributes: [] }],
  },
  group: ['unit_id'],
  order: ['unit_number'],
  limit: 12,
})
```

however I get this error:

`missing FROM-clause entry for table "lessons->exercises"`

Below is my set-up for reference:

```
export const Unit = sequelize.define(
  'unit',
  {
    unit_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    unit_number: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    unit_title: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
)

export const Lesson = sequelize.define(
  'lesson',
  {
    lesson_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    language_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: Language,
        key: 'language_id',
      },
    },
    unit_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: Unit,
        key: 'unit_id',
      },
    },
    lesson_num: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  timestamp
)

export const Exercise = sequelize.define(
  'exercise',
  {
    exercise_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    lesson_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: Lesson,
        key: 'lesson_id',
      },
    },
    exercise_num: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    exercise_completion: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
)

// Associations
Unit.hasMany(Lesson, { foreignKey: 'unit_id' })
Lesson.belongsTo(Unit, { foreignKey: 'unit_id' })
Lesson.hasMany(Exercise, { foreignKey: 'lesson_id' })
Exercise.belongsTo(Lesson, { foreignKey: 'lesson_id' })
```